# Prove that there exists a number divisible by 1999 with digit sum 1999

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

My nephew in the secondary school asked me how to solve the problem as stated in the title. Honestly, I do not have any idea how to do it:

> Prove that there exists a positive integer number such that 1999
>   divides it, and the sum of all of its digit is also 1999.

Can anybody shed some light on how to solve it?
Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Corollary of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182943/divisibility-by-sum-of-digits?rq=1).

Comment: Now the harder question: what's the smallest such positive integer that satisfies these conditions?

Comment: I don't know if this answer is right, therefore sorry if i'm wrong.

If exist a number $n$ with digit sum $1999$, $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ because $1999\equiv 1 \pmod3$. 

Therefore $n=3k+1$( with $k$ integer) but this number to be divisible by $1999$ is necessary that $k\equiv 666\pmod {1999}$.

 Therefore $n$ can be written in the form $$n=3(1999p+666)+1$$
but I don't know if exist a integr $p$ such that digit sum of $n$ is $
1999$

Comment: @nneonneo 11111.......111(1999 times)000000000000000000........(idk times )

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because $10$ is coprime to $1999$ there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $10^k\equiv1\pmod{1999}$. It follows that $1,10^k,10^{2k},10^{3k},\ldots,$ all leave remainder $1$ when divided by $1999$. Therefore the number

$$
S=1+10^k+10^{2k}+\cdots+10^{1998k}
$$
is divisible by $1999$. Furthermore, the decimal expansion of $S$ has $1999$ ones and the rest of its digits are all zeros.

Comment: Because $1999$ is a prime, we can use $k=1998$ by Little Fermat.

Comment: What a wonderful solution! I have thought about the problem several days but could not able to solve it. Thank you very very much!

Comment: How did you know where to begin?

Comment: @David: I'm not sure. I've seen/used similar ideas to solve other problems. For example the question of proving that if $m$ is coprime to ten, then $m$ is a factor of some repunit (= an integer with a decimal expansion with all digits equal to $1$). The starting point there is also that $m\mid 10^k-1$ for some $k$. Here that trick didn't quite work. While $(10^{1998}-1)/9$ is divisible by $1999$, its decimal expansion has only $1998$ digits. All are equal to $1$, so the digit sum is only $1998$. A modification was needed.

Answer (score 22):

Here's another solution.

Note that
$1999$ has digit sum $28$, while $2 \cdot 1999 = 3998$ has digit sum $29$.
Since $28$ and $29$ are relatively prime, and $1999 > 28 \cdot 29 - 28 - 29$, $1999 = 28a + 29b$ for some $a, b > 0$ (see [Chicken McNugget Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem)).
Then just string together $a$ copies of $1999$ followed by $b$ copies of $3998$:
$$
\underbrace{199919991999 \cdots 1999}_{a \text{ copies of } 1999}
\underbrace{399839983998 \cdots 3998}_{b \text{ copies of } 3998}.
$$
This is clearly divisible by $1999$,
and its digit sum is $28a + 29b = 1999$.

Comment: 1999 has digit sum 19?

Comment: @GOTO0 Lol. sorry. fixed.

Comment: Oh, it is also a nice solution! Interesting approach! Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice! And good job finding an earlier version of this question. At least your solution, unlike mine, gives a different approach!

Comment: I think the $\ge$ should be a $\gt$ or not?

Comment: @IvoBeckers That's right, yeah. Sorry for all the errors. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 11,111:
**1...1 (n times) * 1999 = 2221..10889** with n-4 "1" in results (=2,221...*10^(n+3)).
e.g.

- 11,111 * 1999 = 22,210,889
- 111,111 * 1999 = 222,110,889, and so on

**Proof:** Let's suppose that it's true for n (it's true for n=5, 6 as above), for n+1:
1.11. * 10^(n+1) * 1999 =
1.11. * 10^n * 1999 + 10^(n+1) * 1999 =
2.221.. * 10^(n+3) + 1.999 * 10^(n+4) =
2.2211.. * 10^(n+4) what we had to prove.
Where 1.11. * 10^n represents the number consisting of n+1 "1" and 2.221.. * 10^n represents the number described above.

Sum of digits of 22,210,889 is 32 and it's increased by one each step.
**2221..10889 (1968 "1" digits)** has the sum of digits of 1999 and it's divisible by 1999 as it's equal to 1999 * 1..1 (consisting of 1972 "1")

Comment: Thanks! This is also an interesting approach!